# Contact Form 7: Optional text to appear when a dropdown menu option is chosen

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I created a contact form in Wordpress, using Contact form 7 - plugin.

I was wondering if I could make an optional text to appear below when choosing one of the options in it.

For example, if I give a 7 options for a mobile service provider in my form, but would like to show some text when choosing one of them, is it possible?

Also, I would like to do the same with another menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this either by using some js and css or you can use conditional field https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

https://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-7-conditional-logic/20278821